# Error at launch touchpad-indicator

Tags: touchpad

I'm interested by installing touchpad-indicator but when I try to open it it crash. Here is the error:

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, type `cat ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf` and the output should look *something* like:

```
{"disable_on_exit": false, "show_notifications": true, "is_working": true, "on_m
ouse_plugged": false, "disable_on_typing": true, "VertEdgeScroll": true, "start_
hidden": false, "enable_on_exit": true, "HorizEdgeScroll": true, "natural_scroll
ing": false, "shortcut_enabled": false, "first-time": false, "TapButton2": 3, "s
econds": 5.0, "VertTwoFingerScroll": true, "TapButton1": 1, "HorizTwoFingerScrol
l": true, "disable_touchpad_on_start_indicator": false, "shortcut": "c", "touchpad_enabled": true, "CircularScrolling": false, "version": "1.1.0-0
extras15.04.3-src", "autostart": true, "theme": "dark", "TapButton3": 0}
```

If it doesn't exist, or it's empty, create an empty json file by typing:

```
echo '{}' > ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf
```

And see if that allows touchpad-indicator to start.

Answer (score 0):

@heynnema can't comment since post is too long.

hey, thanks for helping me !
It seems that i already have the file.
Here what i have when i type the cat command.

"natural_scrolling": false, "is_working": false, "shortcut": "c", "theme": "light", "TapButton2": 3, "start_hidden": false, "TapButton3": 0, "HorizTwoFingerScroll": true, "VertEdgeScroll": true, "touchpad_enabled": true, "TapButton1": 1, "seconds": 2, "disable_on_exit": false, "version": "", "first-time": true, "HorizEdgeScroll": true, "shortcut_enabled": false, "disable_on_typing": false, "show_notifications": true, "disable_touchpad_on_start_indicator": false, "VertTwoFingerScroll": true, "on_mouse_plugged": false, "enable_on_exit": true, "autostart": false, "CircularScrolling": true}

Comment: It's missing the leading {, or is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: ps: to reach me, use @heynnema in a comment, not in the body of a question :-)